# Integrating Keras Deep Learning model into Android without Converting into Tflite

Tags: java, android, keras, deep-learning, mobile-application

My question is about using `Keras.h5` model into mobile application.
I have downloaded a trained Keras model in `.H5` format and I want to integrate this model (which I have downloaded) in to Android Studio for predicting app.
Is there any way to do that without converting this model into `tensorflow` lite (tflite). Because when I tried to convert the model an `ValueERR` generate.
So I just want to use `model.h5` for my mobile.

PS: DONT want to convert it into `TfLite`.

I tried to convert in tensorflowlite but error generate every time.

Comment: without converting it to lite, you can convert your h5 model to a .pb file and then use cv2's dnn module to load from tensorflow graph

Comment: This is a comment because I don't know if precise solution to your problem is possible. You can convert keras model to ONXX (open neural network exchange) from ONXX you can convert it to any model but I suggest you to convert it  Caffe2 (it is known to be deployable on mobile devices).

Comment: thanks for your reply